# Proving Renyi's result on the order statistics of the exponential distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, beta-function

The [Wikipedia article on order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#) mentions the following result on the order statistics of an exponential distribution with rate parameter, $\lambda$:

$$X_{(i)} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum\limits_{j=1}^i \frac{Z_j}{n-j+1} \tag{1}$$

It provides no proof of this. How do I prove it?

---

My attempt:

We know that to get X_{(i)} for a distribution with inverse CDF $F_X^{-1}(x)$, we first get the corresponding order statistic of the uniform ($U_{(i)}$) and then apply the inverse CDF to it.

We know that $U_{(i)} \sim B(i,n-i+1)$. And the inverse CDF of the exponential distribution is: $F_X^{-1}(x) = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{\lambda}$.

This means that the distribution of $X_{(i)}$ should be: $-\frac{\log(1-U_{(i)})}{\lambda}$

Also, $1-U_{(i)} \sim U_{(n-i)}$. So, the distribution of the order statistic becomes:

$$X_{(i)}\sim -\frac{\log(U_{(n-i)})}{\lambda}$$

We have a Beta inside a logarithm. Don't see a path to equation (1) except maybe expressing the Beta as a Gamma and then noting that the Gamma is a sum of exponentials?

Comment: It can be formally shown using a transformation as used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2793341/321264), which is essentially a result due to Sukhatme: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/272509/119261. Also discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/509909/321264 and its linked posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be shown quite directly. Fix an $i$. Then note that $$ P(X_{(i+1)} -X_{(i)}> x| X_{(i)} = y) = P(X_{(i+1)} > x+y|X_{(i) } = y).$$

Now, the latter probability is that of finding that the smallest of $n-k$ exponential random variables is bigger than $x+y$, given that each is at least $y$. But, due to the independence, and the memorylessness of the exponential distribution, this just works out to $n-i$ independent exponentials being bigger than $x$, i.e. $$ P(X_{(i+1)} - X_{(i)} > x| X_{(i)} = y) = e^{-\lambda (n-i) x}. $$
But, since the right hand side is independent of $y$, we can integrate over the conditioning and conclude that $X_{(i+1)} - X_{(i)}$ has the distribution of a $\mathrm{Exp}( \lambda (n-i))$ random variable. Further, this random variable is independent of $X_{(i)}$

In fact, yet more is true - instead of conditioning over only the value of $X_{(i)},$ we could have conditioned on the values of $X_{(0)} := 0, X_{(1)}-X_{(0)}, X_{(2)} - X_{(1)}$ and so on all the way to $X_{(i)} - X_{(i-1)}$ without changing the conclusion or the reasoning (again, this critically relies on the memorylessness of the exponential law). This means that

1. $ \{ X_{(i+1)} - X_{(i)} \}_{i = 0}^{n-1} $ are mutually independent,
2. $X_{(i+1)} - X_{(i)}$ is $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda (n-i))$ distributed, which in turn is the same as the law of $Z/\lambda(n-i)$ for a standard exponential $Z$.

But now the result is obvious - \begin{align} X_{(i)} &= \sum_{j = 0}^{i-1} X_{(j+1)} - X_{(j)} \\ &\equiv \sum_{j = 0}^{i-1} \frac{Z_j}{\lambda (n  - j)}.\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I think I came up with an approach that might work. We've generated $n$ exponentials with rate $\lambda$. Let's start with $X_{(1)}$. It's the minimum of $n$ exponentials. We know this is just another exponential with rate $n \lambda$.

$$X_{(1)} \sim \frac{Z_1}{n \lambda}$$

Now, we're at $X_{(1)}$, and there are $n-1$ exponentials to go. By the memory-less property, the additional time it'll take for the next exponential to arrive from here is simply the minimum of $n-1$ exponentials. So,

$$X_{(2)}\sim \frac{Z_1}{n \lambda} + \frac{Z_1}{(n-1) \lambda}$$

And we can take this all the way to $i$.

Comment: Oh - didn't notice this. I'll leave my answer up just because it has slightly more detail. BTW I think this argument is from an old paper of Renyi, which I recall being quite nice, you might want to look for it.