# Probability with ordered statistics and exponential distribution involved

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

Assume that $X_1,X_2$ are independent random variables with exponential distribution with the same mean 100. Let $X_{(1)}=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$ and $X_{(2)}=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$. Calculate $P(e^{-0.01X_{(1)}}+e^{-0.01X_{(2)}}>50)$.

I will be able to solve this exercise if $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}$ would be given by simple function of $X_1,X_2$. However I cannot give $f$ for $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})=f(X_1,X_2)$. Could you please help to solve the exercise?

Comment: $e^{-0.01X_{(1)}}+e^{-0.01X_{(2)}}=e^{-0.01X_{1}}+e^{-0.01X_{2}}$

Comment: Yes, you're right :D so the exercise is solved. But if it would be $e^{−0.01X_{(1)}}-e^{−0.01X_{(2)}}$ instead of $e^{−0.01X_{(1)}}+e^{−0.01X_{(2)}}$?

Comment: Then you could first try to find the joint distribution of $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})$.

Comment: have also a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80475/order-statistics-of-i-i-d-exponentially-distributed-sample