# Order statistics of a truncated distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Say I have some exponential distribution with rate parameter 1. The expected value of the order statistics for this has a nice closed form [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80475/order-statistics-of-i-i-d-exponentially-distributed-sample). Now say I want to truncate this distribution to the interval [0,1]. Does the expected value for this also have a closed form solution? More generally if you have a order statistic for a distribution is finding the order statistic for the truncated distribution easy?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll find a nice closed form here. The density for the minimum of $n$ $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ random variables truncated to $(0,1]$ is already fairly nasty:

$$(e-1)^{-n} n e^{n-t} \left(e^{-t}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{n-1}$$