# Expectations of Max Order Statistic on Exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid exponential with scale parameter $\theta$. That is for each $i \in \{ 1,2,...,n\}$, $X_i \sim f_{X_i}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}\exp(-x/\theta) $.
I am interested in the max order statistic $X_{(n)} := \max_{i\in \{1,...,n\}}X_i $. I know the pdf of this max order statistic is $$f_{X_{(n)}}(x) = \frac{n}{\theta} \exp(-x/\theta)(1-\exp(-x/\theta))^{n-1} .$$

For this statistic, I wish to compute the expected value and variance. However, the actual integrals are complicated, and I cannot see how to relate this pdf to an already known distribution.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure it eases the computation, but if you sample the $X_i's$ as $-\theta\log(U_i)$ with $U_i$ i.i.d. Uniform$(0,1)$ r.v., then $X_{(n)}=-\theta\log\min_{i=1}^nU_i$. Thus $X_{(n)}$ has the same distribution as $-\theta\log B_n$ where $B_n$ is a Beta$(1,n)$ r.v. So $\Bbb E[X_{(n)}]=-\theta\,\Bbb E[\log B_n]$, $\mathbb E[X_{(n)}^2]=\theta^2\,\Bbb E[\log^2 B_n]$, etc.

Comment: I think the i'th order statistic from from exponential variables is again an exponential variable.

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3560742/321264 and its linked posts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variance of the maximum of n independent exponentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175307/variance-of-the-maximum-of-n-independent-exponentials)